# Зачем создавать переменную text?

Tags: python, файлы

Изучаю работу с файлами
Смотрю Андрея Андриевского, он с помощью r читал файл, но сказал, что надо обязательно создать переменную и положить туда .read(), мол мы закладываем содержимое файла.
Зачем эту переменную создавать?

```
fr = open("файл.txt", "r")
text = fr.read() # зачем это?
fr.close()
```

Comment: После того, как вы закроете файл, вы уже не сможете получить содержимое файла, вы должны его сохранить в какой-то переменной и с ней дальше работать.

Comment: "он с помощью r читал файл" - r просто показывает, что файл открывается в режиме чтения, сам open или "r" не читает файл. "Зачем эту переменную создавать?" - можно не создавать, можно просто прочитать с помощью fr.read(), и например вывести через print: `print(fr.read())`

Answer (score 4):

Предположим, файл - это книга. В файле/книге хранится стихотворение. Я открыл книгу. Но это еще не значит, что стихотворение уже попало в мою голову и я смогу его рассказать с выражением на новогоднем утреннике. Мне нужно это стихотворение 1) прочитать и 2) запомнить. Вот это прочитать и запомнить и есть сохранение содержимого файла в переменную. Для того, чтобы с этим текстом потом можно было что-то делать.